# silverlight order of execution is weird

Tags: silverlight, xaml, execution

I want login form through which user enter user name and password if it is correct then it will check for first time login if user login for first time then page shd redirect to change password form i want to implement this in silverlight i am using wcf service to write the code  so my logic is i am storing the username in session and then i am redirect it to change password form but sometimes it stores username first and then redirect to change password form which is correct but next time if i execute same form then it first redirect to change password form and then it set the username session so even username is correct it redirect to login form please help me it is making me crazy.
here is my code

gen.SetSessionVariableAsync("uname", username.Text);
 App.Navigate(new UserMgt.Changepassword());

so ideally first line should execute first and second line executes second but here some times first time compile first and some time second time first.

so first i am setting session variable then i want to redirect it to change password page but here sometimes it does proper but sometimes it first redirect to change password then it set to session variable why it is like this?what is the wrong with the order of sequence?

please let me know order of sentence silverlight executes..any help will be highly appropriated.you can email me on foramparikh8884@gmail.com as well.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get async operations to complete in the order in which you write the code. The way to get this working in sequence is by using the Completed event on the Async method and then to execute the following method there as below:

```
gen.SetSessionVariableAsync("uname", username.Text).Complete((o,e)=>
{
   App.Navigate(new UserMgt.Changepassword());
});
```

Note that I am using lambda expressions in the above code fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Because the SetSessionVariableAsync() method is asynchronous then there is no guarantee when it finishes.  If you MUST have that finish first, fire the second method in the completed event for the first method.